# POS Printer release method

Tags: printing, release, opos

I'm developing an application that prints receipts via a POS printer. It is a must that my application can communicate with the POS printer from multiple instances of my application. My POS printer is fit in the network and I want to be able to print from each instance of my application. 
This works fine, but before the Print method, I have to Claim the printer and that takes 0.8 seconds (too long) and after the Print method I need to Release the printer and that takes 3.1 (!!!!) seconds.

Anybody can help me making the claim and release faster?

Comment: Do you have any sample code and have you tried other printers, if not what printer are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Metapace T-3 printer. I haven't tried other printers yet. You can't do much about the code I think, I use the standard POS commands for .NET...
myPosPrinter.Claim(1000);
myPosPrinter.DeviceEnabled = True;
myPosPrinter.RecLetterQuality = True;
myPosPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, text + vbCrLf);
myPosPrinter.Release();

Comment: I havent used that printer, but here are a few things that may be worth a try, (1) Try the latest OPOS CCOs (1.13) if your not using them already (2) Try the printer connected directly to the computer, to see its still slow (may be network overheads)

Comment: I tried to install the latest OPOS CCO's again but I already was using 1.13. Connecting the printer via USB is the next step I will try. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your printer vendor (or whoever provided the Service Object for your printer.)

Your Service Object might be doing extra stuff during ClaimDevice() initialization, such as uploading logo bitmaps to the printer to make sure it's starting from a consistent state.  If you configured your printer's SO with logos, try deleting them to see if that speeds up ClaimDevice().

It may also be doing some kind of delay to ensure the print buffers are empty before reporting the device is closed.  Calling ReleaseDevice() on the device port tells the SO to close the device.  It's possible that closing the port makes it immediately stop printing, which would make it skip the last few print commands, such as "feed and cut paper".  I hope that's not your case because it could take a device firmware update to fix it.